# How to decode a binary array in a PDF using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to decode a stream object inside of a PDF. To provide an example, I have created a simple PDF using word. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I have read some of the basic specifications of a PDF found here: [PDF Specs](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). If you open up a PDF with a basic text editor (Notepad for Windows), you can see that the PDF is a structured object oriented file. This is what the beginning part of the "Hello World.pdf" looks like in the text editor:

```
%PDF-1.7
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 10 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 20 0 R/ViewerPreferences 21 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS7 7 0 R/GS8 8 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 172>>
```

With some reading, I can later decipher what this means; however, I cannot understand the structure of a stream object. This is what a stream object in a PDF looks like:

```
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 172>>
stream
x¥=Â0÷@þÃ`¤1P:ôÃªPPt7kªXÿ?K½áå÷{¤iÐÛ2ËH!?²JC"ñ×X±£¤]àNIî(    Ö
J   Á])Q¾'¡`´:VÄ    ÜÍ÷ê£Aÿò?ÑOi5§ÛðuÃðàË[Öz°q¸ð3ÜÊ/(ùIéXDúi"ð;ª)ðýÚ65
endstream
endobj
```

I would like to be able to turn this into something readable so that I can extract string objects. There should be a string object in this PDF that contains the text "Hello World." It's somewhere in one of these stream objects, but I don't know where to start when it comes to decoding that binary array that makes them up.

I don't have much experience when it comes to character mapping and things related. Does compression have a part in this? If so, how do I deal with it? I would like to be able to decode using python's standard library. If something as simple as decoding this requires a package of some sort, then can you tell me where to start and how this process works?

I understand that the structure of a PDF varies with it's encoding and compression, but for now I would just like to know how to decode this specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @KJ's comment, I was able to see how PDFMinor decompresses a PDF stream. Check out line 248 here: [PDFMinor Source](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/423f851fc20ebd701bc4c8b5b7ba0e7904e18e3b/pdfminer/pdftypes.py#L179)

With this simple PDF, the PDF stream has a "FlateDecode" filter. Apparently, python's built in zlib module is able to decompress this binary array. With just a few uncomplicated lines of code, you are able to decode:

**Code Snippet**

```
import zlib

with open('Hello World.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()

stream_bytes = content[539:699]  # This is where the stream array is
data = zlib.decompress(stream_bytes)
print(data.decode())
```

**Output**

```
"C:\Users\gmbra\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programs\Practice and Learning 2\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/gmbra/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Programs/Practice and Learning 2/test.py"
 /P <</MCID 0>> BDC q
0.00000912 0 612 792 re
W* n
BT
/F1 10.98 Tf
1 0 0 1 72 709.5 Tm
/GS7 gs
0 g
/GS8 gs
0 G
[(Hello Wo)-2(rld)] TJ
ET
Q
q
0.00000912 0 612 792 re
W* n
BT
/F1 10.98 Tf
1 0 0 1 125.42 709.5 Tm
0 g
0 G
[( )] TJ
ET
Q
 EMC
```

There you can see the string object "Hello World," but I'm not sure why it's out of order. If anyone could explain that to me then please comment! Now just adding a simple regex, you can extract the string. I added these lines to the above snippet:

```
import re

matches = re.findall(r'\((.+?)\)', data.decode())
print(''.join(matches).strip())
```

And it outputs:

```
Hello World
```